# Color change on click

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I am building a java app for android. I have a series of linear layouts that when clicked take you to questions. When they are clicked they turn to Dark Grey per my code. After the question is answered you go back to the main page, however the LinearLayout has gone back to the original color. How do I keep it grey until a reset button is clicked?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="question1"
        android:id="@+id/LL1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/garden0"
            android:onClick="question1"
            android:src="@drawable/garden0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/q1"
            android:onClick="question1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

 public void question1(View view){

    LL1 = findViewById(R.id.LL1);
    LL1.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Q1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
};
```

Comment: You have to store your data in SharedPreferences. And delete shared preferences on reset button. And check if shared preferences has file then set color else set no color

Comment: This is one of the purposes of [keeping application state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094346/keep-application-state-on-android) which is also explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#SavingPersistentState)